# Ugly rendering of GLTF with vertex colors

Tags: three.js, 3d, rendering, gltf

**The geometry**

I have a cube represented as a triangular mesh:

[image]

**Applying a color**

Each of the vertices gets a color assigned, to apply a color map onto the cube.

In GLTF format, the mesh is therefore described as follows:

```
{
        "primitives": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "POSITION": 0,
                    "COLOR_0": 2
                },
                "indices": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

**Problem: Ugly rendering**

Unfortunately, this is rendered with ugly artifacts. The color of the three vertices of a face are not smoothly interpolated across the face, but there are brighter and darker zones along the edges of the triangles. This happens with various renderers such as Babylon.js, Cesium, Filament, Three.js.

What's the reason for those artifacts and how can I get a smooth colormap on my cube?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try using a texturemap instead? You could have a simple band of smooth colors in a texture, and use a texture coordinate (instead of a vertex color) to choose the color per vertex.

Comment: I second this. [Just use a texture](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_rotation). Using vertex colors is limited by the triangle density of your geometry, whereas a texture could give you much higher resolution.